# Read and Zip entries files in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parallel-processing, stream, zip

I am trying to create a Zip from a list of files in parallel and stream it to client.

I have a working code where I iterate over files sequentially, but I want it instead to be zipped in parallel (multiple files with >100mb each).

```
using ZipArchive zipArchive = new(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: false);

for (int i = 0; i < arrLocalFilesPath.Length; i++) // iterate over files
{
    string strFilePath = arrLocalFilesPath[i]; // list of files path
    string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFilePath);

    ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(strFileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    using Stream zipStream = zipEntry.Open();

    using FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(strFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    fileStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
}

return new EmptyResult();
```

`Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` do not work with `ZipArchive`

Since `ZipArchive` is not thread safe, I am trying to use `DotNetZip` to accomplish this task.

I looked at the [docs](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/8535b0e7-4827-81ca-8b8c-bb9094cfe286.htm) and here's what I have so far using `DotNetZip`

```
using Stream streamResponseBody = Response.BodyWriter.AsStream();

Parallel.For(0, arrLocalFilesPath.Length, i =>
{
    string strFilePath = arrLocalFilesPath[i]; // list of files path
    string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFilePath);

    string strCompressedOutputFile = strFilePath + ".compressed";

    byte[] arrBuffer = new byte[8192]; //[4096];
    int n = -1;

    using FileStream input = System.IO.File.OpenRead(strFilePath);
    using FileStream raw = new(strCompressedOutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    using Stream compressor = new ParallelDeflateOutputStream(raw);
    while ((n = input.Read(arrBuffer, 0, arrBuffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        compressor.Write(arrBuffer, 0, n);
    }

    input.CopyTo(streamResponseBody);
});

return new EmptyResult();
```

However, this doesn't zip files and send to client (it only creates local zip files on the server).

**Using `MemoryStream` or creating a local zip file is out of the question and not what I am looking for.**

The server should seamlessly stream read bytes of a file, zip it on the fly and send it to client as chunks (like in my `ZipArchive`), but with the added benefits of reading those files in parallel and creating a zip of them.

I know that parallelism is usually not optimal for I/O (sometimes a bit worse), but parallel zipping multiple big files should be faster for this case.

I also tried to use `SharpZipLib` without success.

Usage of any other libraries is fine as long as it read and stream files to client seamlessly without impacting memory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am still pretty sure that using `parallel for` in this case is wrong. Why do you think you will benefit from it? have you tried using single thread? Also this code smells, I'll let you know later what should be changed.

Comment: I am searching for a way to read files and zip them in parallel and stream the zip data to the client. The `DotNetZip` code is broken and doesn't work as intended, but I cannot use `ZipArchive` (which works fine in single thread) in multiple parallel threads.

Comment: I would suggest you lean on the OS ability to "read ahead". Try to open a few files in advance and read their first block, then pass them over to a single threaded zip method. Right now you are only telling the OS about the new file you want at the last moment, blocking your thread from making any progress until the OS can find that file on disk and read it.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman any code snippets on how to "read ahead" files and send them to a stream ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman but os won't overcome serial IO read. What you suggested, as I understand, is a kind of caching files by OS in memory before zipping them. I would not rely on this kind of optimisation.

Comment: Just because your thread is consuming these reads in a single thread, in a single order, does not mean that the OS won't attempt to improve efficiency by issuing multiple overlapped reads via SATA / NCQ, or reordering reads to minimize disk head movement on spinning rust. Plus the OS would prefer the disk is busy, it can and will issue more disk reads than you have yet asked for. Particularly if you open the file for sequential access. But right now the OS is blind because it doesn't even know the name of the next file yet.

Comment: That is interesting. Do you have any paper on that or have any experience? What speed ups we can expect?

Comment: The core concept is *ancient*. You could estimate the minimum execution time by using `C:\> xcopy` to copy some sample files to another disk, which also opens and reads files in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If these files are on the same drive there won't be any speed up. The parallelization is used to compress/decompress data, but the disk IO operation cannot be done in parallel.

Assuming that files are not on the same drive and there is a chance to speed up this process...

Are you sure the `Stream.CopyTo()` is thread safe? Either check the docs or use single thread or set `lock` on it.

EDIT:

I've checked my old codes, where I was packing huge amount of data into a zip file using `ZipArchive`. I did it in parallel, but **there was no IO read** there.

You can use `ZipArchive` with `Parallel.For` but you need to use `lock`:

```cs
//create zip into stream
using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipFS, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
{    
    //use parallel foreach instead of parallel, but not for IO read operation!
    Parallel.ForEach(listOfFiles, filename =>
    {
        //create a file entry
        ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(filename);

        //prepare memory for the entry
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        /*fill the memory stream here - I did another packing with BZip2OutputStream, because the zip was packed without compression to speed up random decompression */

        //only one thread can write to zip!
        lock (zipFileEntry)
        {
            //open stream for writing 
            using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open())
            {
                ms.Position = 0; // rewind the stream
                StreamUtils.Copy(ms, zipEntryStream, new byte[4096]); //from  ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core, copy memory stream data into zip entry with packing.            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, if you need to read the files first, it's your performance bottleneck. You won't gain a lot (if anything) from parallel approach here.

Comment: There's no mention of `Stream.CopyTo()` being thread safe in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-6.0), but `PipeStream` is thread safe so I may use that in the future.

Comment: Changing `input.CopyTo()` to `compressor.CopyTo()` throws an Exception `System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but what is the advantage of using `lock` on `Parallel.ForEach` ? Doesn't it mean that it is essentially the same as normal `foreach` ?                                 
                                                                                                                                               (I know that `ZipArchive` will throw an Exception when using it with `Parallel.ForEach`: `System.IO.IOException: Entries in create mode may only be written to once, and only one entry may be held open at a time.`)

Comment: The advantage of using `lock` is that this is the only way it will work. You cannot write to file/stream in parallel. That is simply impossible. What you can do is to perform parallel packing in memory, as I pointed in comment inside the code, then make files from that. `Lock` creates critical section to ensure only one thread writes to the stream.

Comment: Read the error carefully: only one entry open at a time - ergo you must lock before openning new entry in zip.